# Placing notes in the Kotel/Western Wall

Tags: minhag, kotel-western-wall

Is there any source for the custom to place notes in to the Western Wall? A very prevalent practice in Israel.

And even if there is no source, is it a good idea?

Comment: You might need to go to the mikva first depending on if we view the width of the wall as inside or outside Har HaBayit.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/353/759

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Taamei Haminhagim (p. 270, footnote)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14556&pgnum=283) records a story told by the Minchas Elazar of Munkatch, in which the Ohr Hachaim (R. Chaim ibn Attar, 1696-1743) gave such a note to someone to put into the Wall. So it goes back at least that far.