# Notes in the Kosel

Tags: tefilla, provenance, kotel-western-wall

I was wondering if there is any good source that discusses the reasoning behind the tradition that many have of putting prayer notes into the Kosel (occidental wall) rocks. I am aware of the "legend" brought down in a few seforim about the Ohr Ha'Chaim but I was looking for something more than that - for an understanding of why it is a valid behavior. It seems strange, superstitious and not related to the Jewish concept of tefillah.

Comment: asked already: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13486/placing-notes-in-the-kotel-western-wall?s=1|1.2533

Comment: @DoubleAA -  he changed and improved the question: now he's asking only about the reasoning behind the practice, which was not addressed there. The question there was 'is it a good idea to do so' (which wasn't even answered). The question here is 'what is the reasoning behind it - it seems to be incongruous with the Jewish concept of prayer'. I think it's no longer a duplicate.

Comment: @Jay That q also asks "is there any source for...", no?

Comment: @DoubleAA - True, but here it seems like he's looking for a source that specifically discusses the hashkafa behind it, not just an anecdote of someone doing it. That's the thrust of his question - he wants to know the hashkafa behind it, and he's hoping the source will clarify it.

Comment: @DoubleAA - I'll try to edit the first sentence so it won't be confused with the other question

Comment: @DoubleAA - done. It's definitely not a duplicate now.