# What types of things should a person put on a note that is put into the Kotel?

Tags: minhag, kotel-western-wall

There is a relatively recent custom (see [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13486/placing-notes-in-the-kotel-western-wall)) of placing a note into the crevices of the Kotel. I would like to know if any authorities speak about what a person should write on this note?

Answer (score 5):

Aish HaTorah [says](https://www.aish.com/w/note/46615192.html)

> It is a centuries-old tradition to place a note with a **prayer or
>   request** in the Western Wall.