# Why do Jews write down their wishes to deposit into the cracks of a wall?

Tags: minhag, kotel-western-wall

Why do Jews write down their wishes to deposit into the cracks of the Western Wall (the  western retaining wall of the Second Temple)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placing_notes_in_the_Western_Wall

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13486/27180